# inotifywait script watching a dropbox folder .... cp: cannot stat

Tags: bash, dropbox, inotify

my first question + here we go....

this is a simple script, i had it working before, but now its dead.

when a file comes into a dropbox folder, it appears on the server.
this simple script has inotifywait watching for appends
and doing things i need done with the incoming files, in this case, a simple move
to another folder.

```
    inotifywait -r -m -e attrib /path/to/watched/directory/

    while read dir ev file;

        do 

        cp $file ../123

        done
```

I get this error

```
    cp: cannot stat `121013_0005.jpg': No such file or directory
```

I'm missing something simple, pls school me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you need a `pipe` on the first line
- you should quotes all variables

So finally :

```
inotifywait -r -m -e attrib /path/to/watched/directory |
    while read dir ev file; do
      cp "$file" ../123
    done
```

Comment: omg....that's wat was in the working script and I remeber deleting it...can you explain the pipe. and thx u.

Comment: ok. now I get the first commands output is being "piped" into the input of the while statement. What is a more efficent way of programming this in node.js or python?..to google I go.